# Firefox 87.0 starts slow on Linux 5.8.0

Tags: nvidia, firefox, strace

I have upgraded `firefox` to `87.0` several days ago, but it starts slowly since then.

It works fine after startup, but only takes more time to start.

`firefox -safe-mode` does not speed up the startup.

I run `strace -r firefox` and see the following system call costs too much time:

```
 0.000181 read(3, "PCI_VENDOR_ID\n0x8086\nPCI_DEVICE_"..., 2047) = 255
 2.889336 close(3)
```

It is hard to understand because in my opinion, `read()` does not take long to finish, only system call like `poll()` does.

Another point to mention is that I always set my `nvidia` GPU to `intel` mode to save power. If I set it to `nvidia` mode, then `firefox` starts at a normal speed. I do not know why because `firefox` also started fast before upgrade, but that time my GPU was also set to `intel` mode.